# Laravel 5.4, Eloquent, mass delete redords where relationship count is zero

Tags: laravel-5.4, relationships, eloquent

When retrieving a model with a relationship Eloquent makes it easy to do like so:

```
$model = Model::with('related_model')->where('col_name', 'col_value')->get();
```

This in turn gives us an option to determine the count of records in a relationship

```
$count = count($model->related_model);
```

I have a need to mass delete records when the relationship count is zero:

```
Model::with('related_model')->where('col_name', 'col_value')->get();
```

A regular delete on an ordinary model would look like this:

```
Model::where('col_name', 'col_value')->delete();
```

**Is there a way** to implement a relationship condition in some way in order to delete only Model records that count ZERO relationships.

Something to the tune of

```
// just a mockup of an idea
Model::with('related_model', '>', 0)->where('col_name', 'col_value')->delete();
```

Or will I have to first retrieve the model data and then run a delete statement separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research I discovered that Eloquent offers a `has()` method on the Model class and the solution looks like this

```
Model::has('related_model', '=', 0)->where('col_name', 'col_value')->delete();
```